# Django error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classroom' "

Tags: python, django

I have been working on this project for the last month and this is the first time I have encountered this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classroom'` in countless times of running `manage.py check` on the app. The last change I remember making was commenting out some deprecated views and models, in preparation for removal, but I believe I have restored the code to the last known working version, however I am still receiving this error.

"classroom" is the main application underneath the project. Here is the main directory structure:

```
codex/
|--- codex
|    |--- classroom
|    |    |--- migrations
|    |    |--- templates
|    |    |--- templatetags
|    |    |--- views
|    |    |--- __init__.py
|    |    |--- admin.py
|    |    |--- apps.py
|    |    |--- decorators.py
|    |    |--- forms.py
|    |    |--- models.py
|    |    |--- tests.py
|    |    |--- urls.py
|    |--- __init__.py
|    |--- asgi.py
|    |--- settings.py
|    |--- urls.py
|    |--- wsgi.pyt
|--- manage.py
```

The "classroom" urls are included in the "codex" urls.py
The INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'ckeditor',
    'classroom',
]
```

"ckeditor" is a third party RTF editor for extended text entries required in the app.

At this point, I'm not quite sure where I should be looking for the error. Nor what further information is required to solve the problem.

Comment: where was the manage.py file exists?

Comment: You need to move the `classroom` directory up a level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to move classroom folder to root of project beside manage.py or use `codex.classroom` instead of `classroom`

Comment: My bad - I left out  `manage.py`. It is at the same level as the root of project.

Comment: classroom is in root of project? in your question its in 2nd codex directory

Comment: `classroom` is in 2nd codex directory as shown in the directory diagram. manage.py is in the project root as now shown. This is the structure I have been using since inheriting the project a month ago.

Comment: Well, that must have been the issue. I apologize, I did not remember (it was probably an accident) moving `classroom` to the second `codex` folder, but once I moved it back up to the project root, everything ran fine. Thanks for forcing me to reevaluate the directory structure.